# In React-Big-Calendar Month, can you scroll down week by week?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have built a react big calendar app that I want the ability to click a button and have it basically move the calendar down a week.  React Big Calendar's month view shows me 5 weeks of 7 days.  For example, when showing September 2023, it starts with August 27th (a Sunday) and ends with September 30th (a Saturday).  I want to be able to click my button and have it show me September 3rd (a Sunday) to October 7th (a Saturday)

Currently, as far as I can tell, it gets the current date and then shows me the month that date is in and I am unable to adjust what dates the calendar is showing me... except jumping to the next month of course.

here is my current code (trimmed down)
Many thanks in advance if anyone can help with this one... I've been struggling for about a week on it now.

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop'
import moment from 'moment'
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css'

export default function MyCalendar() {
  const [isSelectable, setIsSelectable] = useState(true);
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);
  const [modalCreateJob, setModalCreateJob] = useState(false);
  const [modalEditJob, setModalEditJob] = useState(false);
  const [modalCompanyHours, setModalCompanyHours] = useState(false);
  const [slotClickedOn, setslotClickedOn] = useState();
  const [eventClickedOn, setEventClickedOn] = useState();
  const [refreshMe, setRefreshMe] = useState(false);
  const [calSize, setCalSize] = useState(900);
  const [newComapnyHours, setNewCompanyHours] = useState();
  const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
  const DnDCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar);

  const handleMyButtonClicked = () => {
    // Help me
  }

return (
    <div>
      <button>My Button</button>
      <div className="mainContentHolder">
        <SideBar />
        <DnDCalendar
          className="DnDCalendar"
          localizer={localizer}
          events={allEvents}
          views={['month', 'agenda']}
          startAccessor="start"
          endAccessor="end"
          draggableAccessor={(event) => true}
          selectable={isSelectable}
          resizable={false}
          onSelectEvent={handleEventClicked}
          onEventDrop={handleEventDrop}
          onSelectSlot={handleSelectSlot}
          popup
          style={{ height: calSize, margin: "20px", zIndex: 1 }}
          dayPropGetter={checkIfOverHours}
          tooltipAccessor={tooltipContent}
          eventPropGetter={(event) => {
            let style = {
              background: event.color,
              color:
                event.color === 'rgb(172, 236, 253)' ||
                event.color === 'rgb(255, 255, 0)' ||
                event.color === 'rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.623)' ||
                event.color === 'rgb(255, 63, 172)'
                  ? 'black'
                  : '',
            };
            
            let startIndex = event.title.indexOf("--") + 2;
            let endIndex = event.title.indexOf("/");
            let totalHoursInJob = event.title.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
            
            if (parseInt(totalHoursInJob) - event.perDay < 0) {
              style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 0 0 3px red';
            } else {
              style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 0 0 1px black';
            }
            return { style };
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```